# Need to find a way to list my shipping carriers in the same line as my shipping cost

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
var carriers = category.SelectMany(o => o.Methods).Select(c => c.Carrier).Distinct();
<tr>                                    
    <td id="tableTitle2" class="bottomBorder">Shipping Cost<br/><br/>Shipping Carrier</td>

    @foreach (var interval in category.OrderBy(o => o.Cost))
    {
        <td class="bottomBorder">$@interval.Cost<br/><br/>@carriers</td>
    }
</tr>
```

So basically, in my shipping prices table I have, I have the shipping cost, as seen in the lambda. However, I also want to add in the carriers to their respective cost. For instance, I have the cost of $40 dollars in my table, and its respective carrier would be USPS. That is defined in my `var carriers` variable. How can I iterate thru my carriers inside the foreach loop so that I can have them listed together respectively? If I add in another foreach loop, I get unnecessary duplicates, and the table's formatting looks bad.

I know my `@carriers` is incorrect but I put it there to explicitly display where I want the shipping carriers to go. This image should help clarify:[image]

Comment: @Amy Sorry I was in the midst of editing the post and thought they disappeared. Still learning my way around using the templates here.

Comment: @sazar97 it seems like you need to GroupBy based on Carrier before you order by cost.

Comment: @DavidL so something like this? ```@foreach (var interval in category.GroupBy(m = m.Carrier).OrderBy(o => o.Cost))```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right for the layout you'll want to end up with something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Shipper</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
  </tr>
<!-- Being loop -->
  <tr>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td>Carrier</td>
  </tr>
<!-- End loop -->
</table>
```

Ordering by cost will result in anything being split up if the costs by carrier isn't the same. Might be helpful to sketch out the logic to figure out where you're going wrong on that one.

Comment: I just added an image to the post that should really help clarify what I'm trying to get. Let me know that you think! thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you like to get two querys and build a nested table list.
So...
1. At your model you need a relationship key (CarriersCustId in Carrier Model).
2. A list type of Cust inside your Carrier Model.
3. Query cust and carriers separated.
4. Join them using ForEach expression Lambda.

```
//First query
var carriers = _context.Carriers.Select(c => c.Carrier).ToList();
//Second query
var cust = _context.Custs.Select(c => c.Custs).ToList();

carriers.ForEach(ca=>{
    //Object List float cust inside your Carrier Model
    ca.ListOfCusts = new List<Carrier>();
    ca.ListOfCusts = cust.Where(cu=> cu.CarriersCustId.Equals(CarriersId)).FirstOrDefault();
});
//Get MoreLinq on NuGet package to use DistinctBy
var result = carriers.DistinctBy(CarriersId).ToList();


 //On View nested foreach do get carries and cust
<table>
  <tr>
    @foreach (var itemCarriers in Model)
    {
      <td>@itemCarriers.Id</td>
      <td>@itemCarriers.Name</td>
      <td>@itemCarriers.Price</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            @foreach (var itemCust in itemCarriers)
            {
              <td>
                @itemCust.Cust
              </td>
            }
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    }

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing the layout of the table, like adding more rows or columns, is not allowed at this time. Your response however is helping me understand a potential solution a bit better, and if I solve it I will post it here. thanks